# In R: create a list of matrices based on different column options

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a way to somehow create a ton of different matrices based on different column options of an original data set...

The desired output for the example below would be 6 different matrices(named: Matrix1, Matrix2, Matrix3, Matrix4, Matrix5, Matrix6) with the different matrices made from the column options in the columns_data. The output could be a list of the matrices as well.

```
data <- structure(list(average_Ca = c(1473014.143, 3682684.657, 1821912.382, 
                                      2748744.864, 1185459.179, 1293030.749), average_Ba = c(20.09711394, 
                                                                                             46.20374139, 28.08272881, 35.38934084, 23.52246807, 30.28871088
                                      ), average_Cu = c(1.272199498, 0.835403944, 0.968764031, 1.388735396, 
                                                        0.936442436, 1.359467342), average_K = c(1657.282202, 823.254076, 
                                                                                                 1023.087054, 1230.217192, 1511.920228, 1773.796743), average_Mg = c(4870.3585, 
                                                                                                                                                                     5068.28785, 5071.13643, 5030.887032, 5553.852132, 5251.224107
                                                                                                 ), average_Mn = c(36.80478114, 40.16526756, 29.69941914, 43.34693371, 
                                                                                                                   43.38435577, 47.9427384), average_Pb = c(4.660350302, 4.549917977, 
                                                                                                                                                            5.440631199, 5.865883295, 6.182218068, 2.320693953), average_Sr = c(112.6037395, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                112.5135425, 115.0819017, 126.0247999, 128.1751451, 138.7221888
                                                                                                                                                            ), average_Zn = c(199.9528515, 148.9285955, 188.3346348, 237.6179019, 
                                                                                                                                                                              218.6832589, 213.7124061), zone_width = c(18.7, 31.31034483, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        21.35294118, 29.1875, 15.6, 25.71428571)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# data
# A tibble: 6 × 10
# average_Ca average_Ba average_Cu average_K average_Mg average_Mn average_Pb average_Sr average_Zn zone_width
# <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#   1   1473014.       20.1      1.27      1657.      4870.       36.8       4.66       113.       200.       18.7
# 2   3682685.       46.2      0.835      823.      5068.       40.2       4.55       113.       149.       31.3
# 3   1821912.       28.1      0.969     1023.      5071.       29.7       5.44       115.       188.       21.4
# 4   2748745.       35.4      1.39      1230.      5031.       43.3       5.87       126.       238.       29.2
# 5   1185459.       23.5      0.936     1512.      5554.       43.4       6.18       128.       219.       15.6
# 6   1293031.       30.3      1.36      1774.      5251.       47.9       2.32       139.       214.       25.7
# >
```

```
columns_data<- structure(list(col1 = c("3 , 4 , 5 , 6", "3 , 4 , 5 , 7", "3 , 4 , 5 , 8", 
                                       "3 , 4 , 5 , 9", "3 , 4 , 5 , 10", "3 , 4 , 5 , 11")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                            6L), class = "data.frame")

# > columns_data
#       col1
# 1  3 , 4 , 5
# 2  3 , 4 , 6
# 3  3 , 4 , 7
# 4  3 , 4 , 8
# 5  3 , 4 , 9
# 6 3 , 4 , 10
```

Example for what Matrix1 would look like

```
Matrix1 <- structure(c(1.272199498, 0.835403944, 0.968764031, 1.388735396, 
            0.936442436, 1.359467342, 1657.282202, 823.254076, 1023.087054, 
            1230.217192, 1511.920228, 1773.796743, 4870.3585, 5068.28785, 
            5071.13643, 5030.887032, 5553.852132, 5251.224107), dim = c(6L, 
                                                                        3L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("average_Cu", "average_K", "average_Mg"
 # >   Matrix1
# average_Cu average_K average_Mg
# [1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359
# [2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288
# [3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136
# [4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887
# [5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852
# [6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224                                                                       )))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `apply`-function

```r
my_list <- apply(columns_data, 1, function(i) list(as.matrix(data[, as.integer(unlist(strsplit(i, " , ")))])))
```

or little easier to read

```r
my_list <- apply(
  columns_data,
  1,
  function(i) {
    idx <- strsplit(i, " , ") |>
      unlist() |>
      as.integer()
    
    data[, idx] |>
      as.matrix() |>
      list()
  }
)
```

This returns

```r
$`1`
$`1`[[1]]
     average_Cu average_K average_Mg average_Mn
[1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359   36.80478
[2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288   40.16527
[3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136   29.69942
[4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887   43.34693
[5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852   43.38436
[6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224   47.94274


$`2`
$`2`[[1]]
     average_Cu average_K average_Mg average_Pb
[1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359   4.660350
[2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288   4.549918
[3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136   5.440631
[4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887   5.865883
[5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852   6.182218
[6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224   2.320694


$`3`
$`3`[[1]]
     average_Cu average_K average_Mg average_Sr
[1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359   112.6037
[2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288   112.5135
[3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136   115.0819
[4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887   126.0248
[5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852   128.1751
[6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224   138.7222


$`4`
$`4`[[1]]
     average_Cu average_K average_Mg average_Zn
[1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359   199.9529
[2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288   148.9286
[3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136   188.3346
[4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887   237.6179
[5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852   218.6833
[6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224   213.7124


$`5`
$`5`[[1]]
     average_Cu average_K average_Mg zone_width
[1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359   18.70000
[2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288   31.31034
[3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136   21.35294
[4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887   29.18750
[5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852   15.60000
[6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224   25.71429


$`6`
$`6`[[1]]
     average_Cu average_K average_Mg average_Ca
[1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359    1473014
[2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288    3682685
[3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136    1821912
[4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887    2748745
[5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852    1185459
[6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224    1293031
```

For example

```r
my_list[[1]]
#> [[1]]
#>      average_Cu average_K average_Mg average_Mn
#> [1,]  1.2721995 1657.2822   4870.359   36.80478
#> [2,]  0.8354039  823.2541   5068.288   40.16527
#> [3,]  0.9687640 1023.0871   5071.136   29.69942
#> [4,]  1.3887354 1230.2172   5030.887   43.34693
#> [5,]  0.9364424 1511.9202   5553.852   43.38436
#> [6,]  1.3594673 1773.7967   5251.224   47.94274
```